# To make clear with a note between brackets

Tags: grammar

I am searching for the word in English which stand for: 
( to make clear with a note between brackets )
I check it on the internet but has no result.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean *parenthetical phrase*?

Comment: ... or [parenthetical definition](https://www.englishonline.net/writing/demo/technical/lessons/2.html)

Comment: This is not parenthetical. I mean which word is stand for the words in the brackets. I think about the word remark or something like this. My dictionary shows the word " chua ". Is it right?

Comment: Neither your question nor your comment is clear. What do parentheses have to do with anything if you're not talking about something parenthetical?

Comment: 'Chua' is not an English word. A phrase in brackets to make the meaning of something clear could be described as an explanation or clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To add an explanation in parenthesis or in the margin of a text is "to gloss" the text. The comment itself is a gloss.

> **gloss (2)**     [source Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gloss)
>
> **noun**
>   1. A translation or explanation of a word or phrase.
>
> 1.1  An explanation, interpretation, or paraphrase of a text.
>
> **verb** [with object]
>   1. Provide an explanation, interpretation, or paraphrase for (a text, word, etc.)